# How to use SignalR for Distributed Databases in MVC using LINQ queries?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have three databases for a Web Application (MVC), if any change happens in any database reflect it in web application `asynchronously`.

Comment: is databases in different layer of same project or other places ??

Comment: Its not in same project layer, its on other place- @Kiran